# $(location).attr('href'); not working

Tags: javascript

I do not know why but I have problems with this code. The banner is displayed on every page although it has specified the attribute $(location).attr('href') you can help me?:

```
<div id="bottombar">
<div class="bottom-content">
<a href="http://www.cliente.org/" target="_blank"><img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/banner/bottom-logo.png" alt="player-logo" /></a>
<a href="http://www.cliente.org/" target="_blank"><img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/banner/bottom-txt.png" alt="player-slogan" /></a>
<img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/banner/bottom-download.png" alt="player-download" />
</div>
<div id="bottombarClose"><p>Chiudi</p></div>
<script type="text/javascript"">
$(document).ready(function() {
var currentUrl = $(location).attr('href');
if(currentUrl == 'http://www.esempio.net/') 
$('#bottombar').show();
$("#bottombarClose").click(function() {
$('#bottombar').hide();
});
});
</script>
</div>
```

CSS Code:

```
  div#bottombar {
  background-image: url(images/banner/player-bg3.png);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  bottom: 0;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
  height: 100px;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: fixed !important;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 99999;
  display:none;
}

.bottom-content {
  bottom: 0;
  height: 97px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -495px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 960px;
  z-index: 10;
}

#bottombarClose {
  cursor: pointer;
  float: right;
  padding: 55px 10px 0 0;
}
```

Comment: what is 'location' in your code?

Comment: Why do you think `$(location).attr()` should work at all?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't you mean just `location.href`?

This is assuming you are talking about [`window.location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location) and not something else.

> Returns a Location object, which
>   contains information about the URL of
>   the document and provides methods for
>   changing that URL. You can also assign
>   to this property to load another URL.

Location is *not an element in the dom* thus jQuery can not select it.

So your code would be like so:

```
var currentUrl = window.location.href;
```

Comment: To be fair, one can use jQuery with non-DOM objects like `window` and `document` but these are special cases.

Comment: `window` and `document` _are_ DOM objects. They are not DOM `element`s.

Answer (score 2):

`location` is not a DOM [Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element), it is a [Location object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location#Location_object).
You are trying to create a jQuery object from it, but it does not make sense.

Use this instead:

```
var currentUrl = window.location.href;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 var currentUrl = window.location.href;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `var currentUrl = window.location.href` instead. This will return the location of the current page.

Answer (score 0):

ok, I made ​​the change in this way, but did not seem to work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var currentUrl = window.location.href;
if(currentUrl == 'http://streamingdb.net/')  
$('#bottombar').show(); 
$("#bottombarClose").click(function() {
$('#bottombar').hide();
});
});
```

then I added a "display:none" to div#Bottombar and everything works. Thanks to all of your time.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of

```
$(location).attr('href');
```

use

```
currentUrl = location;
```

Comment: Hello everyone,

I modified the code so it does not work what is wrong?: