# jQuery isn't working in Firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox

i have a big problem with that javascript doesn't work with my javascript code. What do i need to change:

```
      <script type="text/javascript" src="script/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">


    $(function () {


    var url = 'http://www.gester.nl';
    var english_page = 'index-eng';




  if ($.cookie('nummer_1') != null) {
    if (window.location.href != '/' + $.cookie('nummer_1')) {
        window.location.href = '/' + $.cookie('nummer_1');
    }
}

    $('#english').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.cookie('nummer_1', english_page, { expires: 999 });
        $(location).attr('href', 'index-eng');
        alert('English was set as the default language');
        $.removeCookie("nummer_2");
    });
    $('#english').hover(function() {
        $(this).css('cursor','pointer');
        });


});


    </script>
```

I have to make this text post longer but it works with IE and EDGE, i need to test Opera also. Can please someone show me in what the code needs to be changed. Because i know nothing about javascipt codes.

It skips the alert and the alert box goes away. It doesn't remove my cookie with the $.removeCookie("nummer_2");

Those are the biggest problems because when it doesn't remove the cookie it will go back and forth too 2 pages.

Thanks in advance, thanks for your time.

Giovanni

Comment: What is `$(location).attr('href', 'index-eng')` doing?  It looks like you’re trying to load a different page in mid-function.

Comment: @James Looks like he created a redirect to an English version of his site.

Comment: @DawidLoranc I wasn’t sure if it was valid jquery, [this question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5474121/location-attrhref-not-working) seem to suggest it’s not.

Comment: @James It works, he "jquered" window.location object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because Firefox stops executing code after a change of location.

You have to change code lines order from:

```
$(location).attr('href', 'index-eng');
alert('English was set as the default language');
$.removeCookie("nummer_2");
```

to:

```
alert('English was set as the default language');
$.removeCookie("nummer_2");
$(location).attr('href', 'index-eng');
```

Also, I noticed that you set `cursor: pointer` in JS. Why? Better use (in CSS stylesheet):

```
#english:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: yes, i didn't even know that when i changed my code to something else. Thanks for your answer and for your time. Yeah i didn't come up with the css code , i dont know why haha. Thanks