# JQuery href adding coldfusion token to the URL

Tags: jquery, coldfusion

I am creating a redirect using JQuery based on .cfc (component) response, but it is adding the CFID and CFTOKEN to the URL and it is not redirecting.

I have a basic form:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" role="form">
    <fieldset>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control" placeholder="E-mail" name="userEmail" id="userEmail" type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="userPassword" id="userPassword" type="password" value="">
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input name="remember" type="checkbox" value="Remember Me"> Remember Me
            </label>
        </div>
        <input class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block" type="button" onClick="loginTest();" value="Login">
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Then, the .js calls the component sending the useremail and userpw.

```
function loginTest(){
        if($("#userEmail").val() == ''){
            // alert
            return;
        }
        if($("#userPassword").val() == ''){
            // alert
            return;
        }

        data = {
            UserEmail:  $("#userEmail").val(),
            UserPW: $("#userPassword").val()
        };

        $.ajax({
            type: "get",
            url: 'components/login.cfc',
            data: {
                method:"ajaxLogin",
                data: JSON.stringify(data)
            },
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(result) {
                var url = 'index.cfm?p=30';
                $(location).attr('href', url);
            },
            error: function (error){
                    console.debug(error);
            }
        });
}
```

The component just do validations and set some session variables.

```
private any function login(data){
    // Queries to check user
    // ...
    // ...

    /*
        Set some session varaibles
        session.Test = 'ABC';
    */

    return '0';
}
```

When I click on Login button, everything works and it tries to redirect the page. However, it just sets the CFID and CFToken to the URL and does not redirect.

```
mysite.com/index.cfm?CFID=664628&CFTOKEN=42734ff2bf67b603-54DF7374-D3FE-675B-7950040D96BED9D9
```

Does anyone know why it is happening?

Chrome Network Screenshot issue:
[image]

Thanks

Comment: You need to do: location.href = url;

Comment: Charles, is it relate to the question? It is what I am doing, but using JQuery.

Comment: @myTest532myTest532 your code says `$(location).attr('href', url);` This should be replaced by something different. How is it even supposed to work?

Comment: Do you know JQuery? $(location).attr('href', url); is the same as location.href = url. Anyway, I replace to location.href = url and got the same problem

Comment: What's going on in that index.cfm? You're redirecting to ?p=30, but the URL you end up on with the CFID, is missing the param. Any chance the index.cfm has a cflocation in it? Can you use the network tab in devtools to see what's happening? I suspect it's redirecting twice - once to index.cfm?p=30 and again to the CFID URL.

Comment: Gary, something odd is happening. Firs of all, it works for Firefox, but not for Chrome. Then, I look the Chrome network and it is redirecting to the URL with the CFID because the first request with ?p=30 is returning status 302 (Just Chrome, firefox works fine). I am adding the Chrome Network screenshot. Does it make sense to you?

Comment: 302 is a temporary redirect - it's what you'd get from a cflocation if you don't specify a status. The fact that you say it's working in Firefox is interesting - I'd suggest that there might be a contextual difference, such as cookie data or browser caching. Try Chrome in incognito mode, and post the contents of index.cfm

Comment: Chrome in incognito mode also returns 302. Could it be the rewrite configuration in my server? Firefox return status 200. I am using the JQuery/Javascript for the location, not cflocation, so is there a way to specify a status? Thanks

Comment: $(location).attr('href', url) just adds an 'href' attribute to an element with a variable reference of 'location'. I use jQuery a lot and I'm pretty sure what you've written, is not a replacement for 'location.href'...

Comment: OK. I apologise. Apparently, you are correct. Been using jQuery for decades and I never knew this. I have learnt something new today:)

Comment: Maybe you need to use an absolute URL. Try it and see what happens.

Comment: No needs for apologizes. We are always learning. I still stuck with this 302 issue using Chrome. I can't use absolute URL because my website can be accessed by 2 different domains. Actually, one is subdomain, but changes the CSS for sub domain

Comment: If it was server configuration, I'd expect the issue to occur on all browsers. The fact that the site can be accessed by two domains, and that one is a sub domain, is important information... the application will have been instantiated twice, and those cookies can easily get confused... I've had pretty unpredictable results with that config myself. Nevertheless, I still think the issue is likely to be in the CFML logic, either in your index.cfm or possibly in Application.cfc. If I were you, I'd be stepping through the code in index.cfm line by line.

Comment: Thanks. One more interesting detail. It works fine for the main domain, just the sub domain and Chrome gets the issue. I set up userID in the session variable (session.userID) when someone clicks on login. My code checks if session.userID exists, if not it is redirected back to the login page (kind of timeout. My session timeout is 15 mintues). For the subdomain, using Chrome, when the page redirects after clicking on login, all the session variables are lost. Found the problem, not the solution lol

Comment: I, too, know jQuery for many years and never had the idea to use `$(location)`. I use jQuery where it simplifies my work.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5474121/location-attrhref-not-working

Comment: Yeah, that sounds like something you might have difficulty with when using the same app on a tld, and a sub-domain. In my experience the best solution is simply, do not do this! ;)

Comment: I agree. I need this sub domain because it is a new customer and they want their name in the URL

Comment: So... when you access the URL from the tld and the subdomain, you're hitting the same codebase, right? Unless you're setting domain level cookies (which, in this case will most likely cause you a whole host of issues), you should be getting a different CFID and CFToken cookie on each URL. What's your `this.name` in your `Application.cfc`? If you change that so that it's dynamic based on the host name, you should spawn two identical applications. Give that a go if it's not the case already.

Comment: Yes, it is the same code.I changed the application name, but still get the same problem. Do you mean change to the host name?

Comment: No, I mean make the name dynamic, so that it's different depending on which URL you access the application from. Something like `this.name = 'yourAppName_' & cgi.server_name;`. 
If that works, it might be an idea to limit it so that it only accepts the domain names you know - otherwise someone could spoof loads of domains to eat up your server memory for a DOS attack. Something like: `this.name = 'yourAppName' & ListFindNoCase('your.list.of, different.domains', cgi.server_name) ? cgi.server_name : 'hardcoded.domain';` <-- not tested, but basically that.